# Unable to use my own NPM library with bare imports and encountering a 404 file not found error

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I have developed an NPM library that convert a color model into another one (ex: Hex to HWB).
It is designed to be used in various JavaScript projects, regardless of whether they are frontend or backend, and with or without frameworks.

### Here's the structure of the project:

[image]

Note: I didn't bother showing the `commonjs` folder as it has the same folder structure as in the ES6 one, nor the `test` as it's not relevant to the issue I'm encountering

The library is built using TypeScript and compiled to JavaScript using the TypeScript compiler, it consists of a class with methods to convert a color from one model to another and retrieve all color models for a given color, here's a simplified content of these files:

In the `src/classes/color-conversion.classes.ts` file (simplified):

```js
// 
import {
  RedGreenBlue,
  HueSaturationLightness,
  HueWhitenessBlackness,
  HueSaturationValue,
} from "../variables/color-types.variables"; //TS types

export class AbstractConversionMethods {
 fromRgbToHex(color)...
}

export class ColorConverter extends AbstractConversionMethods {
 constructor(currentModel: string,
    color:...){...}

 convertTo(targetModel:...){...}

}
```

In the `src/index.ts` file:

```js
export {
  AbstractConversionMethods,
  ColorConverter,
} from "./classes/color-conversion.classes";
```

Also, here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "@lephenix47/color-converter",
  "version": "1.0.6",
  "description": "This is a versatile color conversion library for JavaScript. It provides a convenient way to convert color values between different color models, including RGB, HEX, HSL, HWB, and HSV. With @lephenix47/color-converter, you can effortlessly convert colors, normalize them to a consistent format, and retrieve color values in various color models.",
  "main": "dist/lib/es6/index.js",
  "module": "dist/lib/commonjs/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "ts": "rm -rf dist/lib && tsc && tsc --build tsconfig.es5.json",
    "publish": "npm publish --access=public"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/LePhenix47/Color-converter-npm-library_Younes-Lahouiti.git"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist/lib/**/*"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "color",
    "conversion"
  ],
  "author": "color models",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/LePhenix47/Color-converter-npm-library_Younes-Lahouiti/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/LePhenix47/Color-converter-npm-library_Younes-Lahouiti#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  }
}
```

### Problems encountered

After installing my own NPM library and setting up my test folder with this structure:

[image: Folder structure to test my library]

**I am facing 2 issues:**

1. ***Unable to use bare imports:***
   When attempting to import the library using bare import statements this way:

```js
import { ColorConverter } from "@lephenix47/color-converter"
```

I get this error:
[image]

2. ***404 file not found error with relative imports***:

Even when using a relative path:

```js
import { ColorConverter } from "../node_modules/@lephenix47/color-converter/dist/lib/es6/index.js"
```

I receive a 404 error in the console, indicating that the file
cannot be found:

[image]

### Troubleshooting attempts

I have attempted to troubleshoot the issues by removing the `export` keyword from the library classes and manually deleting the `.d.ts` files in the `dist` folder after the compilation.

However, these steps did not resolve my problems

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to overcome these issues and successfully use my library

Here's the GitHub repo in case you want to see the entire codebase:
https://github.com/LePhenix47/Color-converter-npm-library_Younes-Lahouiti